# Python 3: Solving arrayChange in CodeFights

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on the arrayChange level of Code Fights Arcade. This is the objective:
  You are given an array of integers. On each move you are allowed to
  increase exactly one of its element by one. Find the minimal number of
  moves required to obtain a strictly increasing sequence from the input.

Example

For `inputArray = [1, 1, 1]`, the output should be
  `arrayChange(inputArray) = 3`.

I have written this code in Python 3:

```
def arrayChange(inputArray):
   original = inputArray[:]
   count = 0
   if len(set(inputArray)) == 1:
      return ((len(inputArray)-1)**2 + (len(inputArray)-1)) / 2
   elif sorted(inputArray) == inputArray:
      return 0
   for index, value in enumerate(inputArray):
      if index != len(inputArray) - 1 and value > inputArray[index+1]:
         inputArray[index+1] += abs(inputArray[index+1] - value) + 1
      elif index != len(inputArray) - 1 and value == inputArray[index+1]:
         inputArray[index+1] += 1
      elif index == len(inputArray) - 1 and value < inputArray[index-1]:
         inputArray[index] += inputArray[index-1] - value + 1
   print (inputArray)
   for index, value in enumerate(inputArray):
      count = count + abs(value - original[index])
   return count
```

It passes all the non-hidden tests but fails the 7th hidden test. Can someone please help me figure out what bug my code has? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the return value in the first `if` statement is correct? Shouldn't the number of moves be `n(n-1)/2` where n is `len(inputArray)` ?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj Lets say n = 8. 8-1 = 7. 8*7 = 56. 56/2 = 28. Correct ans. should be 36 which is the result of the statement I used in my code.

Comment: Ohh, my bad, didn't expand the formula. I'm running some tests on the code. If it's any help, you can return `int` of the count.

Comment: your formula returns 28 too, check it once.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj Oh sorry. Yes. Thats what both return. my apolgies. so we've figured out that that's not the problem. any other suggestions?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj clarifications: 28 is actually what both(your formula and my formula) are supposed to evaluate to

Comment: No other suggestions mate :/ , I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
elif sorted(inputArray) == inputArray: return 0
```

Take this array for instance: `[1, 1, 2]`. It is the same sorted. However, the output should be 2: `[1, 1 + 1, 2 + 1]`. You should be able to just remove that conditional to pass all cases.

On a simpler note:

Your code can be simplified to this:

```
def arrayChange(inputArray):
    sum = 0
    q = inputArray[0]
    for i in inputArray[1:]:
        if i <= q:
            sum += q-i+1
            q = q+1
        else:
            q = i
    return sum
```

Comment: yes, thank you. I had already figured this out long back, but had forgot to take the question off. anyway, thank you for your time and I will accept your answer so its not like you wasted your time.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry to necro the post. I'm a codefighter too could I get your ign to add you? thanks :)

Comment: No problems :) Good to know you're a codefighter as well. I just joined 2-3 months back or so. My ign is fake_e1 Thanks again mate

Comment: This is a great solution, but please never use a built-in function name like `sum` as a variable name, as doing so will overwrite the builtin function name such that you won't be able to use `sum()` as a method to do adding afterwards, unless you restart your REPL.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the error, I presume it is failing because the execution is exceeding the time limit. It seems code is taking time especially when sorted and enumerate functions are used with large set of array. Remember Test cases checks for all edge cases. The one including 3 ≤ inputArray.length ≤ 10^5 and -10^5 ≤ inputArray[i] ≤ 10^5.

Here is simple solution and it passed all cases.

```
def arrayChange(inputArray):
    cnt,temp = 0,0
    while len(inputArray) > 1:
        if inputArray[0] >= inputArray[1]:
            temp = (inputArray[0]-inputArray[1])+1
            inputArray[1]=temp+inputArray[1]
            cnt=cnt+temp
        inputArray.remove(inputArray[0])
    return cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def arrayChange(inputArray):
    moves = 0
    for i in range(1,len(inputArray)):
        if inputArray[i] <= inputArray[i-1]:
            #moves to increase to one number greater than previous
            moves += inputArray[i-1] - inputArray[i] + 1
            #modify current to previous plus one
            inputArray[i] = inputArray[i-1] + 1
    return moves
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Java:**

```
 int arrayChange(int[] inputArray) {
    int numberOfMovesRequired = 0;
    final int length = inputArray.length - 1;
    int i = 0;
    while( i < length){
        if(inputArray[i] >= inputArray[i+1]){
            inputArray[i+1] = inputArray[i+1] + 1;
            numberOfMovesRequired++;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return numberOfMovesRequired;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 easier solution that passes all test cases

```
def arrayChange(a):
    count, i = 0, 0
    original = a.copy()

    while i < len(a):
        if i != len(a) - 1 and a[i] >= a[i+1]:
            count += abs(a[i] - a[i+1]) + 1
            a[i+1] += a[i] - a[i+1] + 1
        
        i += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In java,

int arrayChange(int[] inputArray) {
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<inputArray.length-1;i++){
        if(inputArray[i]>=inputArray[i+1]){
            int temp=inputArray[i+1];
            inputArray[i+1]=inputArray[i]+1;
            c=c+inputArray[i+1]-temp;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: How does the translation of other answers into a different language help to answer the original question? Please read [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying, including [another well received answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67106250/14267427).

Answer (score -1):

Concise Python Solution

```
def arrayChange(inputArray):
    a = 0
    for i in range(1, len(inputArray)):
        if inputArray[i] <= inputArray[i - 1]:
            f = (inputArray[i - 1] - inputArray[i]) + 1
            inputArray[i] = inputArray[i - 1] + 1
            a += f
    return a
```

Comment: Hey @Jayanth just wanted to kn why u'r adding a 1 here: inputArray[i] = inputArray[i - 1] + 1 and not "f" value ? Thanks in advance .